# Expand one and collapse all using bootstrap in angular template

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have one table where each row has a button and on click it will expand and show some data that is calculated in my component but problem is on button click it is keeping other button expanded and showing latest calculated data in all expanded row. I want on expansion particular row it will collapse other rows.

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of datas | search:'Name':query;let i = index">
         <td> <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" attr.data-target="#demo{{i}}" (click)="calculateValue(data.Name,data.value)">{{data.Name}}</button>
         <tr id="demo{{i}}" class="collapse" id="insidetr">
           Price:{{value | number : '1.2-5'}}
           </tr>
         </td>
         <td>{{data.LastValue | number : '1.2-8'}}</td>
        <td>{{data.High | number : '1.2-8'}} </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

this is my component:

```
  calculateValue(market,value){
        var data1 = "data1";
        var data2="data2";
        if (market.includes(data1)) { 
        this.value=this.calculateValue(value);
        }
      }
```

Please suggest me what to do. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use the ng-bootstrap module.
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples

Right now, there is no way for your other rows to know that another row is open. You need to keep track of your open row.

```
  Private activeRow = -1; //declare this in your component

  calculateValue(market,value, row){
    this.activeRow = row;
    var data1 = "data1";
    var data2="data2";
    if (market.includes(data1)) { 
    this.value=this.calculateValue(value);
    }
  }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of datas | search:'Name':query;let i = index">
         <td> <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-info" [attr.aria-expanded]="this.activeRow == i" aria-controls="demo{{i}}" (click)="calculateValue(data.Name,data.value, i)">{{data.Name}}</button>
         <tr id="demo{{i}}" [ngbCollapse]="this.activeRow = i" id="insidetr">
           Price:{{value | number : '1.2-5'}}
           </tr>
         </td>
         <td>{{data.LastValue | number : '1.2-8'}}</td>
        <td>{{data.High | number : '1.2-8'}} </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Luke, I will try that. If any issue I will post a comment here or I will make it as answer.